# How can I get the image url in a Wordpress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a theme for wordpress. And I have many images in 'images' folder. But when I take the page in browser it is not comming.

My code is

### index.php

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/mindset.jpg" width="145" height="32" /></a></li>
```

**Is there any function for getting the image path in wordpress ?**

Comment: Can try <?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
src="<?php echo base_url()?>your_theme_dir/image_dir/img.ext"
```

As well

```
src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/image_dir/img.ext"
```

Comment: src="<?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/imagelogo.gif"  ???? also good? Doesnt work for me. Works for css but not for image.

Comment: this seems like it directs to the parent theme if you have a child theme

Comment: By default, WordPress doesn’t allow you to run PHP code in posts or pages. So how are you doing it?

Comment: @kble can't remember but google search result for "wordPress doesn't allow you to run PHP code" has it today

Comment: Just as an additional option, you can use `<?=base_url()?>` instead of `<?php echo base_url()?>`

Comment: `<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/` → This one worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

[get_template_directory_uri();](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) 
 
This function will help you retrieve theme directory URI, and can be used with your images, your example below:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/mindset.jpg" />
```

Comment: This example will not work, if you are using a child theme.

Comment: works while using the parent theme.

Answer (score 8):

I had to use Stylesheet directory to work for me.

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/image.png">
```

Comment: You probably use a child theme. This function points to the stylesheet directory of the activated theme (your child theme) whereas the `get_template_directory_uri();` would point to the parent theme directory (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/#comment-1797), which would be the wrong path in this case. But your answer should be the accepted one by now.

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me when using a child theme

Answer (score 7):

You need to use

```
 <?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>
```

It returns the directory of the current WordPress theme.

Now for example, if your theme has some image named `example.jpg` inside some folder name `subfolder` folder in the `images` folder.

```
 themes
   |-> your theme
          |-> images
                |->subfolder
                      |-> examples.jpg
```

You access it like this

```
 <img class="article-image" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?> /images/subfolder/example.jpg" border="0" alt="">
```

Comment: given the example, this was the most helpful answer in here! many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/image_dir/img.ext"`
 worked for me for wordpress 3.6 i used it to get header logo using as

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo.jpg">
```

Comment: This answer is identical to the accepted answer posted over 2 years ago. What was the point of posting this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing a child theme you can use:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>-child/images/example.png" />
```

**get_template_directory_uri()** will return url to your currently active theme (parent theme), then you add -child/, then add path to your image (the example above assumes your image is at `<child-theme-directory>/images/example.png`)

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend the following:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img-folder/your_image.jpg">
```

It works for almost any file you want to add to your wordpress project, be it image or CSS.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since Ian already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up once you have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

If your img folder is inside your theme folder, just follow the example below:

```
<img src="<?php echo  get_theme_file_uri(); ?>/img/yourimagename.jpg" class="story-img" alt="your alt text">
```

Answer (score -1):

You asked of **Function** but there is an easier way too. When you will upload the image, copy it's URL which is at the top right part of the window ([View Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQS0m.png)) and paste it in the `src='[link you copied]'`. Hope this will help if someone is looking for similar problem.

Comment: Please don't use this solution. You will have several problems when using a hardcoded path to your logo, i.e. when you change your domain to SSL or you change the wp-content - directory. Try using a solution with `<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>`.